# How to add tag and category in a php CMS and then display them in posts?

Tags: php, tags, content-management-system, categories, procedural-programming

I'm beginner at php. i'm building a simple CMS with php from scratch. i could build the CRUD part successfully but now i'm going to add tag and category to my posts. i tried my own ways but none of the worked!!

As you know tags and categories are linked to a page with related posts. for example if click on a tag/category "tech", it will refer you to a page with posts related to "tech" keyword.

I'm going to build somthing like what i just told but i don't really know how to do that. what i'm really confused about is how to find a way to know which tag/category belongs to which post! i searched a lot but everything is about WordPress!!!

could you please help me with some tutorial. i'd like to build my CMS with **PROCEDURAL** programming not **OOP** because i'm beginner!